# OpenShift WordPress Theme Developer workflow

Tags: linux, wordpress, git, openshift, paas

I create a application with Cartridges,

- PHP 5.4
- MySQL 5.5
- phpMyAdmin 4.0

I commit my WP file, plugin and themes into GIT. 
In my `.gitignore`, i added

```
wp-content/uploads
```

I did go through the book "Getting Started with OpenShift", as the book chapter 8 said

> “The other directory available to you is the OpenShift data directory,
>   which is currently at $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/data. We use the
>   environment variable OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR to point to this location. ”
>
> “The data directory is where your application should store its files
>   and put configuration settings, download themes, or generally anything
>   you want to survive restarts and Git pushes.”

Excerpt From: Steven Pousty and Katie J. Miller. “Getting Started With OpenShift.”

I access to SSH. When I upload my media in WordPress, It is store inside

```
$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/1.jpg
```

1.How do I pointed it to?

```
$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/uploads
```

1. If that is the case, in my `.openshift/action_hooks/deploy` file, I had added this script

   if [ ! -d ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads ]; then
       mkdir ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads
   fi

   ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads   ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}php/wp-content/

However, the soft link script does not did it job, during my `GIT PUSH`, it shows the following error.

```
remote: ln: target `/var/lib/openshift/[ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/php/wp-content/' is not a directory: No such file or directory
```

my guess is, the `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/1.jpg` , the `uploads` folder already removed before the script do it job.

How do I keep the uploads folder content in such a situation. OpenShift expert kindly help in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I had few attempt of the build script, I finally found out what is my problem.

To answer my own questions

1. How do I point it.
   Create a symlink. During the GIT push, it will definitely delete your uploads folder ($OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wp-content/uploads/).

This is the code you should use, just remove the php folder after the repo.

```
if [ ! -d ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads ]; then
    mkdir ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads
fi

ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads   ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}wp-content/
```

I hope it's help.

Answer (score 1):

This file has plenty of examples

https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy

The problem is that with every git push we are going to overwrite that directory.

I think a better idea is with every build rsync contents from your repo over to the data directory where it expects to find the themes (rather than doing the symlink)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do study the deploy file in wordpress-example. AS you said every time we push there directory will be overwrite. Below is my two questions, I hope you can help to answer it.

1.Is that means that NO possible to set my upload folder point to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/uploads?

2.Is there any script can run the rsync in build/deploy script? What I had research all need to be done in SSH, don't you think it can be automated? What I want is just copy from $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR then after GIT PUSH had done, copy back to the original folder.

Comment: You should only use OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/uploads got uploads.

I also think you should modify your build action hook (that I link to above) script to rsync the contents of repo_dir to data_dir at the points you want.